# Extract this xml file from function and save on local disk with php

Tags: php, xml

I have the following code below, and I want to save that xml file on disk, how can I do this?

```
<?php

// CAPTURE THE BUFFERED OUTPUT AND WRITE A FILE
$rss = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('my_rss.xml', $rss);

?>
```

Comment: You've been here for three years, so you should know to format your code properly when asking a question.

Comment: and the problem with this code is... what? without seeing what's happening in the "capture" part, the two lines you do have look ok.

Comment: I want to see that how can i save my_rss.xml on disk and then work with it,the rest of codes is ok,just how save my_rss.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_put_contents() writes directly to a file. That means your file is "saved" when you use this function. Also, if the file name does not exist, it is created.
This being said, the first parameter of the function should be the path to your file. Right now, it is simply going to save my_rss.xml in the same directory as your php file.

If the file is not getting created, you probably have a permission problem or something. Make sure you have php errors turned on to see that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Kaveh asked for saving file to local disk, to user computer, but

> file_put_contents

PHP statement save file to directory on web server where is used script.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.